# Why does Swift require explicit parameter types even when they can be inferred from default values?

Tags: swift, language-design

From page 6 on in *The Swift Language*, it is clear that the language designers pride themselves on the fact that while Swift is strongly typed, programmers often don't have to worry about types, because they are inferred from context.

I find it odd, therefore, that explicit types are required even when default parameter values make the parameter types clear.

For example, *String* is required in this declaration:

```
func assign(motto: String = "Winter is coming") { /* ... */ }
```

even though the type of *motto* is clear here:

```
func assign(motto = "Winter is coming") { /* ... */ }
```

and is easier to read than the legal code.

*Do you know or can you imagine why this is?*

I could find no change requests in Evolution in this area. (https://apple.github.io/swift-evolution)

**One investigation**

My first thought was that allowing programmers to omit parameter types would allow them to build complex types within parameter declarations that could be difficult to read:

```
func update(inventory = [
    ("Daenerys", ("dragons", -1)), 
    ("Cersei", ("children", -3))
    ]) {

    /* ... */

}
```

But that danger doesn't bother the language designers in variable declarations. This is legal Swift:

```
var houseData = [
    ["Stark": ["Sigil": "Dyer Wolf", "Motto": "Winter is coming"]],
    ["Lannister": [
        "Sigil": "Lion", 
        "Motto": "Hear me roar", 
        "Saying": "A Lannister pays his debts"
    ]]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be to make the lives of the people who read your code easier.

Let's say I am reading your code and I saw

```
func foo(param = bar.baz) {
```

It would take me a second to realise what type `param` is. I need to go to the definition of `bar.baz` and see what type that is.

Unlike a variable declaration, the type of a parameter is much more important because users of your method need to know the type, so that they know what to pass to your method.

---

Also, making parameter types required also makes the [spec](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_parameter-clause) simpler to write. There is only one case:

[image]

Otherwise there would be two cases: one with an optional type annotation, and another one with an optional default argument clause.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't know that non-literals could be legal default values.